# Django Queryset order by a not directly related model's field

Tags: python, django

I have the following model design:

```py
class Boat(models.Model):    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False)
    harbour = models.ForeignKey(Harbour, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

class Harbour(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, null=True, related_name='city_harbours',  on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    county = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)


class NearestCity(models.Model):
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, related_name='city', null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    near_city = models.ForeignKey(City, related_name='near_city', null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    weight = models.DecimalField(null=False, max_digits=25, decimal_places=20)
```

## Brief explanation:

- A `Boat` belongs to a `Harbour` and a `Harbour` belongs to a `City`.
- Not all Cities have a harbour related.
- `NearestCity` is a table where is stored how close is a city the rest of the cities: The `weight` is a decimal value that indicates how far is *city* from _near_city_ . The more smaller is the 'weight' value, the more close is city to near_city. For example:

```
city     near_city      weight
----    ---------       ------
London   Rome           2.210103
London   Manchester     0.113134
```

It means that Manchester is closer to London than Rome.

## Problem to solve:

Given a name of a city  without any harbour related, for instance Berlin, a want to return all the boats of those closest cities that do have at least one harbour related. This Boat's queryset must be ordered by `weight` DESC.

I am really newbie with django queryset and I tried to solved using `annotate` with `subqueries`, `aggregations`, etc.. but  I could not achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try [raw sql](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/sql/). Something like this should work:

```
city = selected_city_pk
sql = """
    SELECT b.name, nc.weight, nc.near_city_id
    FROM appname_nearestcity nc
    JOIN appname_city c ON near_city_id = c.id
    JOIN appname_harbour h ON near_city_id = h.city_id
    JOIN appname_boat b ON h.id = b.harbour_id
    WHERE nc.city_id = %s
    ORDER BY nc.weight, b.name
"""
results = Boat.objects.raw(sql, [city,])

for r in results: print(r.id, r.name, r.weight, r.near_city_id)
# boat_id, boat_name, weight, near_city_id
>> 14 b-0-h-sochi-0 10 6
>> 15 b-0-h-sochi-1 10 6
>> 16 b-0-h-sochi-2 10 6
>> 17 b-1-h-sochi-2 10 6
>> 18 b-2-h-sochi-2 10 6
>> 11 b-0-h-rome-0 55 5
>> 12 b-1-h-rome-0 55 5
>> 13 b-2-h-rome-0 55 5
>> 4 b-0-h-brasilia-0 56 4
>> 7 b-0-h-brasilia-1 56 4
>> 10 b-0-h-brasilia-2 56 4
>> 5 b-1-h-brasilia-0 56 4
>> 8 b-1-h-brasilia-1 56 4
>> 6 b-2-h-brasilia-0 56 4
>> 9 b-2-h-brasilia-1 56 4
>> 1 b-0-h-beijin-0 93 2
>> 3 b-0-h-beijin-1 93 2
>> 2 b-1-h-beijin-0 93 2
```

Remember to replace table names with actual table names from your DB because Django adds app name prefixes to them.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This queryset returns the NearestCities.. But I need the Boat ordered by weight. Because after that I need to apply another filter over Boat objects

Comment: Have you read the link? This queryset returns manually selected fields and items that may not be closely related to a certain model. If you need filtering, you can also do it in the raw sql.

Comment: Edited the answer with actual (default) table names from DB that would be created by your models.

Comment: Awesome, It runs perfectly.. Thank you very much for your help @Alex K.